# how to find file extension in case of file list?

Tags: python, django

How can i find extension of list of files .I am currently using
os.path.splitext which is not working.Please suggest any other method in case of file list.

My code goes here:

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('media')
            for f in files:
                p = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
                print p
```

It shows the error `'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'rfind'`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error and the code it seems you are using Django, so you should get the object name and not the object itself 
as:

```
 p = os.path.splitext(f.name)[1]
```

which will give the file name and not the file object.